# IBM WebSphere Portal V8.5 wcm library syndication

Tags: aix, websphere-portal, subscriber, syndication

I have a WebSphere Portal Version 8.5 Cluster on AIX 7.1 with multiple Virtual Portals, working with managed pages and each Virtual Portal has it's own libraries and one shared library for all VPs using syndication of that library to each VP.

i successfully created the syndication pair between the syndicator (WAS base portal) and the subscriber (Virtual Portal) and tested connection between them and all is good (make sense since VP are local on the same server). however when trying to syndicate the library content it stays on Queued status and in the SystemOut.log i see the following error log:

```
[4/25/17 9:33:53:201 IDT] 00004163 PackageConsum E   Unexpected exception thrown while updating subscription: [IceId:  Current State: ], exception: com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.WCMServiceRuntimeException: code: 400
                                 com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.WCMServiceRuntimeException: code: 400
        at com.aptrix.syndication.business.subscriber.CatalogRetrieverTask.getSourceCatalog(CatalogRetrieverTask.java:330)
        at com.aptrix.syndication.business.subscriber.CatalogRetrieverTask.process(CatalogRetrieverTask.java:144)
        at com.aptrix.syndication.business.subscriber.PackageConsumerTask.processPackage(PackageConsumerTask.java:513)
        at com.aptrix.syndication.business.subscriber.PackageConsumerTask.processUpdate(PackageConsumerTask.java:267)
        at com.aptrix.syndication.business.subscriber.PackageConsumerTask$1.run(PackageConsumerTask.java:183)
        at com.ibm.wps.ac.impl.UnrestrictedAccessImpl.run(UnrestrictedAccessImpl.java:84)
        at com.ibm.wps.command.ac.ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.execute(ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.java:90)
        at com.aptrix.syndication.business.subscriber.PackageConsumerTask.doManagedWork(PackageConsumerTask.java:195)
        at com.aptrix.syndication.business.ManagedTask.runWork(ManagedTask.java:62)
        at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.workmanager.AbstractWcmWork.runImpl(AbstractWcmWork.java:162)
        at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.workmanager.AbstractWcmSystemWork.access$001(AbstractWcmSystemWork.java:40)
        at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.workmanager.AbstractWcmSystemWork$1.run(AbstractWcmSystemWork.java:92)
        at com.ibm.wps.ac.impl.UnrestrictedAccessImpl.run(UnrestrictedAccessImpl.java:84)
        at com.ibm.wps.command.ac.ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.execute(ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.java:90)
        at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.repository.PACServiceImpl.runAsPrivileged(PACServiceImpl.java:1878)
        at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.workmanager.AbstractWcmSystemWork.runImpl(AbstractWcmSystemWork.java:87)
        at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.workmanager.AbstractWcmWork.run(AbstractWcmWork.java:146)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.workmanager.impl.WasWorkWrapper.run(WasWorkWrapper.java:44)
        at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:271)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:274)
        at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:797)
        at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.go(WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.java:222)
        at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.ABWorkItemImpl.run(ABWorkItemImpl.java:206)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:804)

[4/25/17 9:33:53:222 IDT] 00004163 SyndicationEx W   Unsuccessful request to send summary: 400
                                 com.aptrix.deployment.wizard.SyndicatorCommunicationException: Unsuccessful request to send summary: 400
        at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.api.syndication.SyndicationExtensionsServiceImpl.sendSummaryToSyndicator(SyndicationExtensionsServiceImpl.java:293)
        at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.api.syndication.SyndicationExtensionsServiceImpl.processSubscriberCompleting(SyndicationExtensionsServiceImpl.java:246)
        at com.aptrix.syndication.business.subscriber.SubscriberTaskManager.processFailedUpdate(SubscriberTaskManager.java:405)
        at com.aptrix.syndication.business.subscriber.PackageConsumerTask.processUpdate(PackageConsumerTask.java:400)
        at com.aptrix.syndication.business.subscriber.PackageConsumerTask$1.run(PackageConsumerTask.java:183)
        at com.ibm.wps.ac.impl.UnrestrictedAccessImpl.run(UnrestrictedAccessImpl.java:84)
        at com.ibm.wps.command.ac.ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.execute(ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.java:90)
        at com.aptrix.syndication.business.subscriber.PackageConsumerTask.doManagedWork(PackageConsumerTask.java:195)
        at com.aptrix.syndication.business.ManagedTask.runWork(ManagedTask.java:62)
        at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.workmanager.AbstractWcmWork.runImpl(AbstractWcmWork.java:162)
        at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.workmanager.AbstractWcmSystemWork.access$001(AbstractWcmSystemWork.java:40)
        at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.workmanager.AbstractWcmSystemWork$1.run(AbstractWcmSystemWork.java:92)
        at com.ibm.wps.ac.impl.UnrestrictedAccessImpl.run(UnrestrictedAccessImpl.java:84)
        at com.ibm.wps.command.ac.ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.execute(ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.java:90)
        at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.repository.PACServiceImpl.runAsPrivileged(PACServiceImpl.java:1878)
        at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.workmanager.AbstractWcmSystemWork.runImpl(AbstractWcmSystemWork.java:87)
        at com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.workmanager.AbstractWcmWork.run(AbstractWcmWork.java:146)
        at com.ibm.wps.services.workmanager.impl.WasWorkWrapper.run(WasWorkWrapper.java:44)
        at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:271)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:274)
        at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:797)
        at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.go(WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.java:222)
        at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.ABWorkItemImpl.run(ABWorkItemImpl.java:206)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:804)

[4/25/17 9:33:53:227 IDT] 00004163 syndication   I   Syndication Summary - Subscriber
Syndicator: IntShared_Syn, URL=http://'Was_Server':10039/wps/wcm/connect?MOD=Synd
Subscriber: IntShared_Sub, URL=http://'Was_Server':10039/wps/wcm/connect/'VP_URL_Context'?MOD=Subs
Status: FAILED
Failure Detail: Update failed on subscriber
Unexpected exception thrown while updating subscription: [IceId:  Current State: ], exception: com.ibm.workplace.wcm.services.WCMServiceRuntimeException: code: 400
Update Type: REBUILD
Start Date: Tue Apr 25 09:33:53 IDT 2017
Finished Date: Tue Apr 25 09:33:53 IDT 2017
Duration:
Total: 0
Total Failed: 0

[4/25/17 9:33:54:613 IDT] 00000136 syndication   I   Syndication Summary - Syndicator
Syndicator: IntShared_Syn, URL=http://'Was_Server':10039/wps/wcm/connect?MOD=Synd
Subscriber: IntShared_Sub, URL=http://'VP_HostName':10039/wps/wcm/connect?MOD=Subs
Status: FAILED
Failure Detail: Terminated without confirmation
Returned non-confirmed response: Not confirmed. Unable to contact subscriber. Check the subscriber to ensure it is active and error free. Also review your network connections and your syndication configuration to ensure the subscriber details are correct.
Update Type: REBUILD
Start Date: Tue Apr 25 09:33:53 IDT 2017
Finished Date: Tue Apr 25 09:33:54 IDT 2017
Duration: 1 second
Total: 0
Total Failed: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WCM Syndication requires HTTP Basis Authentication to be configured and working.

then I needed to make sure that Trust Association is enabled in WAS Console under Security -> Global Security -> Web and SIP security -> Trust association.
confirmed that the box that says Enable trust association is checked.
also ensured the Interceptor com.ibm.portal.auth.tai.HTTPBasicAuthTAI is created and the configuration were correct.
the cause of the error was that in the fields of urlBlackList and urlWhiteList there was use of the variable ${WpsContextRootPath} which i found out that it is not set anywhere so i change it to /wps instead and now the fields are as follow:
urlBlackList = /wps/myportal*
urlWhiteList = /wps/mycontenthandler*

after Restarting the server and retry syndication - it works!.

also you may follow the direction in this link:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/206675/why-do-i-see-occasionally-see-a-popup-box-with-a-t.html

but setting these parameters disabled the servlet of vieweing all items in the libraries...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the ip address instead of the hostname.  or Try adding the VP context to the syndicator/subscriber URLs.